# Jquery cookie if statement not working

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm using the cookie [jquery plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and cannot get my code to execute from the following if statement. The console.log bit works, but nothing else does (changing colour via css or hiding):

```js
  if($.cookie('geo-cookie') == null){ 
    console.log('cookie does not exist vdd');
    $('#header').hide();
  }
  else if($.cookie('geo-cookie') == 1){
     console.log('cookie exists');
    $('#header').show();
  }
```

Comment: Where is the 'changing colour via css' part? Can you also post your HTML, and let us know if there's any console errors.

Comment: have you tried `console.log($.cookie('geo-cookie'))` to check the value is what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 if($.cookie('geo-cookie') === null) { 
        console.log('cookie does not exist vdd');
        $('#header').hide();
    } else if($.cookie('geo-cookie') == 1){
     console.log('cookie exists');
    $('#header').show();
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would help. `==null` returns `true` only for `null` and `undefined` values. Which basically means that you can use `value == null` instead of `value === null || value === unefined`

Comment: Thanks, that helped. It turned out it was the ordering of my javascript files which meant it wasn't executing the .hide() commands because the #header include had been placed after my file with the cookie script in. Thanks!